# What is the right tag for this question?

Tags: discussion, tagging, specific-question

I stumbled on [How to find distance from emitter using TDOA?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927447/88985) because I study hyperbolic geometry and this question was wrongly tagged as such.

But then what is the right tag?

There is no tag on navigation, geometry seems to broad so let's discuss it here :)

Comment: I have added tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) to your question on meta. If you consider the linked question just as an example and you want to discuss a more general issue (e.g., what tag should be used for questions about trilateration, multilateration, etc.), then the tag (specific-question) should be removed. But if it is the case, you should probably make this more clear in your post.

Comment: I do not really have any good ideas for tagging the linked question. I just want to say that adding ([tag:geometry]) as a big umbrella tag will not hurt. (But still it would be nice to add some more specific tag.) From your answer is seems that the question is related to [multilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration). The Wikipedia article you linked in in category [Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Euclidean_geometry) and we have such tag.

Comment: You can also have a look at [other questions about trilateratin](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=trilateration) (and some related topics) to see what tags were used for such questions in the past.